# Can wildcard certificates hide/obscure the hostname in a TLS connection?

Tags: encryption, tls, cloud-computing, protocols, obscurity

I'm trying to increase security for my cloud-based / multi-tenant environment.  I'm considering having clients access an obscure URL such as GUID.myCloud.com.  I will then respond to that guid-based request with customer-specific data.

1. Considering that the certificate itself has a Subject name of *.myCloud.com, does that mean that the TLS protocol itself won't expose my private hostname?
2. Is there any reason to believe that Subject Alternative Names would behave any differently?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll still see server names in client hello SNI extensions.