# Is password less login secure?

Tags: authentication, passwords

Recently I came across this password less login. For authentication, we need to enter an email address and click on a login button. We will receive a link in your email and when we click on that link we will get authenticated.

My question is how much secure it is because when we click on the link it is visible in the network right? so someone who can see the link can access it and login right? or I'm I missing something here? I think people who have access to the network like ISP or someone in the middle can see the URL's we are accessing is that correct?

Comment: "it is visible in the network" -- what network? You mean, if you click on the link in the email, the network/ISP can see the data in the URL? Is the URL using TLS/HTTPS?

Comment: I think what you really want to know is this: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/7705/does-ssl-tls-https-hide-the-urls-being-accessed